# Перенести значение (цифра) из одного файла в другой

Tags: php

Подскажите плиз, как сделать так, что бы цифра в файле менялась в другом файле?

А именно цифра "30" дней

```
<?PHP

class life_time
{


    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }


    private function GetTimeLife($name)
    {
        switch ($name) 
        {
            case 'a_t':
                return 60*60*24*30; // 30 дней
            break;

            case 'b_t':
                return 60*60*24*30; // 30 дней
            break;

            case 'c_t':
                return 60*60*10; // 30 дней
            break;

            case 'd_t':
                return 60*60*24*30; // 30 дней
            break;

            case 'e_t':
                return 60*60*30; // 30 дней
            break;

            case 'f_t':
                return 60*60*30; // 30 дней
            break;


            default:
                return 60*60*24; // время по умолчанию для всех фруктов 24 часа
            break;
        }
    }


    private function GetNameItem($name)
    {
        switch ($name) 
        {
            case 'a_t':
                return "<font color='white'><b>Купон </font><font color='orange'>№1</b></font>";
            break;

            case 'b_t':
                return "<font color='white'><b>Купон </font><font color='orange'>№2</b></font>";
            break;

            case 'c_t':
                return "<font color='white'><b>Купон </font><font color='orange'>№3</b></font>";
            break;

            case 'd_t':
                return "<font color='white'><b>Купон </font><font color='orange'>№4</b></font>";
            break;

            case 'e_t':
                return "<font color='white'><b>Купон </font><font color='orange'>№5</b></font>";
            break;

            case 'f_t':
                return "<font color='white'><b>Купон </font><font color='orange'>№6</b></font>";
            break;

            default:
                return $name;
            break;
        }
    }


    public function AddItem($user_id, $name, $time=0)
    {
        $db = $this->db;
        $now = time();
        if ($time==0) $del = $now + $this->GetTimeLife($name);
        else
            $del = $now + $time;
        $sql = "insert into `db_product_time` 
                (`id_user`, `name`, `date_add`, `date_del`, `status`)
                values
                ($user_id, '$name', $now, $del, 1)";
        $db->Query($sql);
        return ($db->LastInsert()>0);
    }


    public function CheckTime()
    {
        $db = $this->db;
        $now = time();
        $sql = "select * from `db_product_time` where `status`=1 and `date_del`<=$now";
        $db->Query($sql);
        $arr = array();
        if ($db->NumRows()>0)
        {
            while($row = $db->FetchArray()) 
            {
                $arr[] = $row;
            }
        }
        if (count($arr)>0)
        {
            foreach ($arr as $row) 
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $par = $row['name'];
                $user = $row['id_user'];
                $sql = "update `db_users_b` set `$par`=`$par`-1 where `id`=$user";
                $db->Query($sql);
                $sql = "update `db_product_time` set  `status`=0 where `id`=$id";
                $db->Query($sql);
            }
        }
    }

    private function ConvertTime($val)
    {
        $time = (int)$val;
        $m = floor($time / 60);
        $h = floor($m / 60);
        $m = $m - $h*60;
        $s = $time - $m*60 - $h*60*60;
       if($h != 0) return "$h ч $m мин $s сек";
       if($m != 0) return "$m мин $s сек";
       if($s != 0) return "$s сек";
    }


    public function GetTable($user_id)
    {
        $style = "<style>.info_block{height: 50px;float: center;margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;width: 100%;background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #7e0017, #00185d);border: 5px; solid black;border-radius: 10px; text-align: center;} .info_block div{padding: 15px;}</style>";
        $db = $this->db;
        echo $style;
        $sql = "select * from `db_product_time` where `status`=1 and `id_user`=$user_id";
        $db->Query($sql);
        while($row = $db->FetchArray()) 
        {
            $tim = (int)$row['date_del']-time();
            $tim = $this->ConvertTime($tim);
            echo "<div class='info_block'>";
                echo "<div>";
                echo $this->GetNameItem($row['name'])."<font color='white'> - осталось: </font><font color='orange'>".$tim;
                echo "</font></div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```